# Eliminar separação de palavra por quebra de linha - php

Tags: php

Boa tarda pessoal,

O código abaixo extrai o texto de um pdf e imprime na tela.
Só que as separações por quebra de linha não são eliminadas, e as palavras que foram separadas por quebra de linha aparecem da seguinte forma: `'sem - pre'`.

Eu tentei usar `$DCM_conteudo = str_replace(" - ", "", $DCM_conteudo);`, porém somente os hifens são excluídos (e não as quebras de linha) .

Alguém sabe como identificar e excluir as quebras de linha?

```
<?php

// Include conexão com o bd e com Composer autoloader.
include_once 'conexaoBD/conexao.php';
include 'vendor/autoload.php';


ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF8');
set_time_limit(6000);


$file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_fnl = $_FILES['file']['name'];

// Parse pdf file and build necessary objects.
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile($file_fnl);

$DCM_conteudo = $pdf->getText();
$DCM_conteudo = str_replace(" - ", "", $DCM_conteudo);
$DCM_nome = $file_fnl;

echo $DCM_conteudo;

?>
```

*### Att: Pedaço do texto extraído do pdf.*

> Neste ***con - texto***, ganhou destaque a Lei n° 6.458/2019, de autoria dos vereadores, que obriga restaurantes, lanchonetes, bares e similares, barracas de praia e vendedores ambulantes a usar e fornecer a seus clientes apenas canudos fabricados exclusivamente com material biodegradável ou ***reci - clável***.

Comment: Provavelmente a quebra de linha fica após o hífen, então não bastaria remover `" - \n"`?

Comment: preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $yourString ); <- Tenta usar assim pra remover as quebras de linha

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Tentei, e também tentei  " - \n\r" , mas nenhum funcionou.

Comment: @EdwardRamos Também não resolveu.

Comment: Renata, adicione na pergunta um trecho do texto que possua essa parte com o hífen e a quebra de linha para vermos como está

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Adicionei um pedaço do texto extraído do pdf na pergunta, e em destaque, como aparece a palavra separada pela quebra de linha.

Answer (score -2):

Nesse caso da leitura vem de um padrão externo do Adobe, pode experimentar o método junto ao já utilizado.

```
$DCM_conteudo = str_replace("\n", "", $DCM_conteudo); 
$DCM_conteudo = str_replace("\r", "", $DCM_conteudo);
```